# Varchar2 vs date when building data warehouse

Tags: oracle, data-warehouse

Does it make any difference to prefer varchar2 over date data type when building data warehouse in Oracle. My data warehouse is not totally warehouse because date dimension is not necessary (no need for date hierarchy) and it is enough to save date as plain 'MM-DD-YYYY' formatted string. Which data type to use nevertheless?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's do a little cost/benefit analysis, shall we?

### Leave the "date" field as `VARCHAR2`

#### Pros:

- Zero computational cost when formatting the date on a report (as long it always appears in the `MM-DD-YYYY` format).

#### Cons:

- Cannot be indexed (well, in the *chronological* sense)
- Searching computation is increased because of `TO_DATE` calls
- Requires extra computation if the date must appear in a *different* format on some report (for example: `TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(date_column, 'MM-DD-YYYY'), 'DD-MON-YYYY')`)
- The column does not require all values to adhere to a particular date format, increasing the risk of a failure if `TO_DATE` is necessary.

### Change the "date" field to `DATE`

#### Pros:

- Can be searched upon without the overhead of `TO_DATE`
- Can be indexed
- "Bad" values cannot be inserted (although the dates may still make no sense from a business perspective)
- Can be easily formatted

#### Cons:

- I can't think of anything off the top of my head

Hopefully this will help in your particular decision from a *technical* perspective. There is always the *business* (or, *office politics*) perspective:

> date dimension is not necessary

I will fix that for you:

> date dimension is not necessary ***yet***

Suppose you leave the column as `VARCHAR2` and the client comes along and asks to filter some report on this date field. Suppose this is killing the database server and you finally need to convert it to `DATE`. Is it relatively easy to make this change in a production environment at your company? Is there plenty of red tape and forms and change control boards you must fight to make your simple change? If you *do* manage to overcome those hurdles, are you sure that all dates are stored in the same formatting?

Comment: Profound explanation. I'll go for DATE data type.

Comment: +1 There is no excuse for dsigning new databases which store dates as strings.  It's 2011, people!

Answer (score 2):

What does "enough" mean here?  I can see what you lose by not using DATE, but what do you gain that makes this worth considering?  Surely if you are holding a date value, at some point you will want to use it e.g. "sales in March 2011" or whatever?

Answer (score 2):

varchar2 should be avoided because it takes up for space, why use a datatype that takes up much more space than one that does not?

Perhaps disk storage space is not much of an issue these days, but it can save up some RAM space, preventing disk I/O, especially if records containing those dates are accessed frequently.

And if disk I/O is required when retrieving a record, it would be slightly faster because the size is smaller when using date vs varchar2.